# Nginx-ingress-controller failed to start after AKS upgrade to v1.22.6

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform

Kubernetes version : 1.22.6
previously deployed ingress controller through Terraform using chart https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx.

While starting the ingress controller we keep getting the below error message in job **ingress-Nginx-admission-create** and not starting the ingress controller

```
{
  "err": "Get \"https://192.168.64.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/ingress-nginx/secrets/ingress-nginx-admission\": EOF",
  "level": "fatal",
  "msg": "error getting secret",
  "source": "k8s/k8s.go:232",
  "time": "2022-06-30T22:03:16Z"
}
```

I tried a couple of options to delete and re-create ingress-controller using the below command directly but no luck.

```bash
helm upgrade --install \
     ingress-nginx ingress-nginx \
     --repo https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx \
     --namespace ingress-nginx \
     --create-namespace \
     --debug \
     --version="4.1.1" # tried with latest version too
```

Any help, please.

Answer (score 0):

- In order to resolve it, you should try the following:

1. Quote your values when you install it (TF vars. i assume)
2. Allow port 443 to the API server IP address/FQDN.
3. Reprovisioned your Service CIDR within the same network (as a subnet) as the nodes

---

#### Suggestion based upon your update

```
--set controller.hostNetwork=true
```

- Add the above line to your command

```
helm upgrade                     \
     ingress-nginx ingress-nginx \
     --install                   \
     --repo      https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx \
     --namespace ingress-nginx   \
     --create-namespace          \
     --debug                     \
     --version="4.1.1"           \
     --set controller.hostNetwork=true
```